# Drupal: $_POST and MENU_CALLBACK. How works?

Tags: routes, ajax

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131209/how-to-pass-arrays-to-drupal-menu-callbacks) and [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36261/how-can-i-get-post-data-in-a-callback) but nothing is working for me I'd like to create a menu like this

```
$items['login'] = array(
'page callback' => 'mymodule_login',
'access arguments' => array('access content'),
'access callback' => true,
'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
);
```

in order to send a POST to http://www.mysite.com/login.

This is my script in order to generate a POST

```
<?php

define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());

require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

$base_url = 'http://www.mysite.com';
$data = array(
  'username' => 'admin',
  'password' => 'password',
);
$data = http_build_query($data, '', '&');
$headers = array();
$options = array(
  'headers' => array(
    'Accept' => 'application/json',
  ),
  'method' => 'POST',
  'data' => $data
);

$response = drupal_http_request($base_url . '/login', $options);
$data = json_decode($response->data);
```

And this is my callback function

```
function mymodule_login() {
  header('Content-type: application/json');
  watchdog('mymodule',  print_r($_POST, TRUE));
  $result = array("result" => "ok");
  echo drupal_json_output($result);
}
```

The body contains a json with username and password. Everything is ok, except for `$_POST` under function `mymodule_login` that does not work. `$_POST` is empty.

What's wrong? Is there another "drupalic" way?

Comment: Does the body contain only JSON or URL encoded key-value pair? The request body should contain something like: `json=[url encoded json string]` and you will then be able to access it via $_POST['json']. Posting the code for `mymodule_login` would help.

Comment: I updated my request

Comment: Your code (4th revision) looks correct. Did you clear cache ? Show us a var dump of `$response`

Comment: Yes clear all via drush everytime.
watchdog('citynotifier',  print_r($response, TRUE)); gave "Undefined variable: response in citynotifier_login()"

Comment: Here's the [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10947513/1216174)
Content type "application/json" disable $_POST so you must use file_get_contents("php://input")