# $_POST empty in custom callback

Tags: 7

I'm trying to write a custom listener for PayPal Instant Payment Notifications. I've defined a page callback in `hook_menu` as

```
$items['paypal-listener'] = array(
    'title' => 'PayPal IPN Listener',
    'description' => 'Simple test for receiving PayPal notifications',
    'page callback' => 'ipn_test',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
);
```

and my custom callback is

```
function ipn_test() {
    var_dump($_POST);
    watchdog('paypal_ipn', print_r($_POST, TRUE));
}
```

but it's always empty. When testing with postman the response is always

```
array(0) {}
```

Is there something I'm missing? Something that empties out the $_POST array?

The $_POST from PayPal is `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in case that matters.

I have already checked [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/75405/drupal-post-and-menu-callback-how-works), [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131209/how-to-pass-arrays-to-drupal-menu-callbacks) and [this one](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36261/how-can-i-get-post-data-in-a-callback) but none seem to have the answer to why the data is gone.

This doesn't work either

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = json_decode($data, TRUE);
```

**Update**:

OK, it seems as if the chrome app postman can't send POST varibale to a local server properly. I created a simple php script with just `var_dump($_POST)` and while it works fine on an online server, it is empty on my local server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must have been some kind of bug or I set it up wrong because the next day it started working fine.